# setenv seems useless when encounter with execve

Tags: c, linux, execve, setenv

I'm following the project **TINY SERVER** and there is a peice of code shown as below.

This code is used to passing the `cgiargs` to `filename` which is a cgi program.

```
void serve_dynamic(int fd, char *filename, char *cgiargs)
{
    char buf[MAXLINE], *emptylist[] = { NULL };

    /* Return first part of HTTP response */
    sprintf(buf, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"); 
    rio_writen(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    sprintf(buf, "Server: Tiny Web Server\r\n");
    rio_writen(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
  
    if (Fork() == 0) { /* child */ //line:netp:servedynamic:fork
    /* Real server would set all CGI vars here */
    setenv("QUERY_STRING", cgiargs, 1); //line:netp:servedynamic:setenv
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);         /* Redirect stdout to client */ //line:netp:servedynamic:dup2
    execve(filename, emptylist, environ); /* Run CGI program */ //line:netp:servedynamic:execve
    }
    wait(NULL); /* Parent waits for and reaps child */ //line:netp:servedynamic:wait
}
```

In the **adder.c** which is the target cgi program, the code is shown as below.

```
int main(void) {
    char *buf, *p;
    char arg1[MAXLINE], arg2[MAXLINE], content[MAXLINE];
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;

    /* Extract the two arguments */
    if ((buf = getenv("QUERY_STRING")) != NULL) {
        p = strchr(buf, ’&’);
        *p = ’\0’;
        strcpy(arg1, buf);
        strcpy(arg2, p + 1);
        n1 = atoi(arg1);
        n2 = atoi(arg2);
    }
    
    /* Make the response body */
    sprintf(content, "QUERY_STRING=%s", buf);
    sprintf(content, "Welcome to add.com: ");
    sprintf(content, "%sTHE Internet addition portal.\r\n<p>", content);
    sprintf(content, "%sThe answer is: %d + %d = %d\r\n<p>",
            content, n1, n2, n1 + n2);
    sprintf(content, "%sThanks for visiting!\r\n", content);
    
    /* Generate the HTTP response */
    printf("Connection: close\r\n");
    printf("Content-length: %d\r\n", (int)strlen(content));
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
    printf("%s", content);
    fflush(stdout);

    exit(0);
}
```

In my opinion, the `serve_dynamic` function sets the "QUERY_STRING", an environment variable, and the `adder.c` gets the "QUERY_STRING" and use it. But actually in `adder.c`, the `buf` is **NULL**.

Then I try to set `environ` to pass the `QUERY_STRING` and it works. But it's very inconvenient.
I didn't think out why `setenv` function didn't work, and I hope someone can solve my problem.

Comment: Please edit your question - Link to the project you're following? Can you share the full program? What is `environ`, and does it contain the `QUERY_STRING` key/value pair?

Comment: Note that `setenv()` does not modify the thrid parameter of `main()` (i.e: `char *envp[]`) - https://gist.github.com/attie/4506efe1664ea487df0b9ea64124a763

Comment: @Attie `environ` is a standard external variable on Unix. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html

Comment: @Attie but it modifies the global variable `environ`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Wow, I'd forgotten all about that...

Comment: I post the serve_dynamic function and adder.c file.

Comment: This is neither minimal nor reproducible. Minimal means there is no stuff unrelated to the problem (you have a lot of unrelated printfs). Reproducible means anyone can take it as is, compile it, run it, and get the same result you get (I cannot compile or run any of this as is).  A [mre] is **not** a fragment of your real code, it is a piece of code adapted from your real code specifically for asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the exact TINY SERVER project as you did, and I had the exact same problem as you did. I think the 'setenv' function didn't work is because --

We set the environment variable 'QUERY_STRING' in the child process we forked, and then we used execve() to start a new process, which is NOT a child process of the calling process, instead it will replace the child process we forked, so the 'QUERY_STRING' was not shared in the new process.

I think the right way to set environment variable (in the child process we forked) to be passed to the program refered by execve() is like this: newenviron[0] = "QUERY_STRING=VALUE";

and then we will be able to use getenv() to access it in the cgi adder program.

You can refer to: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html

execve(const char *pathname, --,--) executes the program referred to by pathname. This causes the program that is currently being run by the calling process to be replaced with a new program.with newly initialized stack, heap, and (initialized and uninitialized) data segments.

Answer (score 0):

I read the [environ](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) variable agian, and I found I lost to use `extern char **environ`.
After adding this code, the **setenv** and **getenv** can work normally.

Comment: So what you're saying here is you forgot to put: `extern char **environ` in the parent process, and as a result you got some other value in environ, which is why it wasn't working. It sounds like you aliased the environ variable by omitting the `extern`, which is why your original code didn't work, which would not have been discoverable by the code you provided.